# GetDlgItemText returns error 1421

Tags: c++, api, winapi, user-interface

I've used this function and it returns this error so it has to do with the window identifiyer.
But it seems to me like everything is fine,i have set the `HMENU` field in the child window to `101`
then in the child procedure i call:

```
ID = GetDlgCtrlID(hwnd);
length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
```

(hwnd is the local handle of the child window) 
than i have a call to:

```
GetDlgItemText(hwnd,ID,buf,length);
```

buf is an array of type char:

```
 char buf[256] = {0};
```

I have tried running this with `sizeof(buf)` instead of `length` as well. yet it seems like there is still a problem and i don't seem to know what is it.
The buffer stays empty and the error is still comeing up.
I would love to get some help.
So thanks for the help in advance! :)

Comment: 1421 is `ERROR_CONTROL_ID_NOT_FOUND`, so look closer at your `hwnd` and `ID` arguments. Is `hwnd` of a *second* call the handle of a *dialog*? (Do you use dialog at all, as in `CreateDialog`, dlgProc and all that stuff?)

Comment: Well i dont use CreateDialog
I actualy am using subclassing with 
`wpOrigEditProc2 = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong(nhwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG) ChildWndProcp);`
in the child procedure i have the call for these functions i have stated,and when i debug i can see that ID gets the HMENU value, ID is equal to 101 and the handle is set to the child instance.
Infact i was able to run it with no errors some time ago but i modified my code and apperanly it gives out this error so i dont know what is wrong.

Comment: GetDlgItemText() takes the hwnd of the dialog box as its first parameter. Your code implies that hwnd is actually the handle of the control within the dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong.

The problem is here:

```
GetDlgItemText(hwnd,ID,buf,length);
```

But you probably want this:

```
GetWindowText(hwnd, buf, length);
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I was using GetWindowText. but i thought it was to get the window title bar text,but now i understand it better. I got it! :) thnak you.